# Backbutton swap between actionbars

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am currently a second actionbar, i would like to know how to add a back/up button on actionbar2 that changes the actionbar back to actionbar1. How would i do this?

Comment: please rephrase your title.

Comment: Sorry title rephrased now

Answer (score 0):

use this code for enabling back button

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        if (mActionBar != null) {
            mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
```

and in order to show check box you need to implement onClick event or on longClick event and get the position of clicked item and change the visbility of that particular item...

Answer (score 0):

Enable Home up Button in action bar

1.Import android.app.ActionBar

```
   ActionBar customActionBar = getActionBar();
   customActionBar.hide();
   customActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   customActionBar.show();
```

2.Import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

```
ActionBar customActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```